# eliminacion periodica de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde guardo datos que son momentáneos.

Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede hacer un borrado por tiempo, que cada cierto tiempo se borren los datos automáticamente sin necesidad de estar pendiente de eliminarlos manualmente?

No sé si mediante un trigger se pueda hacer esto

```
244931  2019-06-15 00:00:00.000
242840  2019-06-04 00:00:00.000
33810   2015-08-20 00:00:00.000
33700   2015-08-13 00:00:00.000
26193   2015-06-16 00:00:00.000
273245  2019-11-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Puedes crear un job que corra cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Directamente con la base de datos no podrías desarrollarlo, pero existen herramientas (como lo son jobs) que te permiten ejecutar tareas periódicas, también están los mal llamados "demonios" en linux que serviría similar, lo mas recomendable sería truncar la tabla (un sp sería suficiente) y ser llamado desde un job o demonio.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo mejor es tener un procedimiento almacenado que por ejemplo realice un `Truncate table.`

Luego crear un trabajo (`job`) en el `Agente de SQL Server` que llame a este procedimiento. Solo te quedará programar el `job` para que realice el borrado con la frecuencia que quieras.

Si no dispones del `SQL Server Agent`, por ser la versión Express, puedes utilizar la utilidad de línea de comandos `sqlcmd`. Debes crear un archivo `.cmd`, es decir un archivo de texto con esta extensión que contenga por ejemplo:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\Nombreinstancia -d BaseDeDatos -Q "EXECUTE dbo.ProcedimientoAlmacenado"
```

Y creas una tarea en el Programador de Tareas de Windows que ejecute ese cmd con la frecuencia que quieras.

Te dejo un ejemplo del job

Aqui le pones el nombre a tu job
[image: Aqui le pones el nombre a tu job]

Aqui pones la consulta que trunca la tabla que deseas
[image: Aqui pones la consulta que trunca la tabla que deseas]

Aqui pones el cada cuanto quieres que se ejecute tu job, diario, semanal ,mensual y la hora en la que quieres que se ejecute, todo esto a tu voluntad y preferencia
[image: Aqui pones el cada cuanto quieres que se ejecute tu job, diario, semanal ,mensual y la hora en la que quieres que se ejecute, todo esto a tu voluntad y preferencia]

Comment: Solo agregaría la opción de usar `DELETE` en caso de que no haya que borrar todos los datos sino solo los más antiguos, o si hay alguna restricción que evite que se use `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Tambien se podria, si se necesita condicionar pues se haria mediante el delete, si no pues con el truncate basta